# Get HAR without devtools

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I get HAR without devtools? when I try with this code, I recive this error:

code

```
 chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function(result) {
    var entries = result.entries;
    if (!entries.length) {
        Console.warn("Recarregue a pagina, ou inicie o stream");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
        console.log(entries[i]);
    }
});
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getHAR' of undefined
```

I have this code into background.js

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Download Stream",
    "version": "1.0",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
    "description": "Efetua o download do stream",
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "page_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "icon-19.png",
        "default_title" : "Download Stream"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "icons" : {
        "48" : "icon-48.png",
        "128" : "icon-128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. You can only call chrome.devtools.* APIs in the devtools page. (chrome.webRequest API can provide you some information of network requests， except response body.)

Comment: Really? My idea is create an icon left side bookmark star, where I can  see a resume of medias on the page. Can it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply use Chrome API to generate HAR files. But you can capture HAR from Chrome using BrowsermobProxy and Chromedriver using Selenium Server.

Here is an example of using chromedriver with BrowsermobProxy and Selenium:

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import json
import urlparse

server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
url = urlparse.urlparse (proxy.proxy).path
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(url))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options =chrome_options)
proxy.new_har("http://stackoverflow.com", options={'captureHeaders': True})
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")    
result = json.dumps(proxy.har, ensure_ascii=False)
print result
proxy.stop()    
driver.quit()
```

Checkout [Speedprofile](https://github.com/parasdahal/speedprofile) to make life easier.